# custom handler404 => standard error page

Tags: python, django

When I try to use my own view for error 404, I instead get a standard error page. So, what I've done by now:

```
# root settings.py
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '*'
]

# blog urls.py
handler404 = 'views.custom_404'

# blog views.py
def custom_404(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world, I'm a custom error 404")
```

And, besides, to try it locally on `Django` test server, I run it like this:

```
python manage.py runserver --insecure
```

But what I get when I go to some page which does not exist is:

```
Not Found
The requested url blablabla
```

So, for some reason I do not see my own message `Hello world, I'm a custom error 404`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

404 handlers are not per app, they can only be set from the main urls.py.

Comment: I ran into another problem. If I simply show a message, then it's ok. If however I try to use e template page `404.html` which is located in `blog/templates`, then I get Server Error 500. Can you, please, advise me how to solve this problem? PS. settings.py knows about `blog/templates` path and there is a true `404.html` file in that folder.

Comment: I try to render `404.html` like this: `return render_to_response('404.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))`